# Combine prism topics into the caustics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Does anyone see reasons for or against the `caustics` tag including prism topics?

Caustics are not explicitly prism-rendering, but caustics are often prismatic in small degree.

Or, could we create a `prism` tag for following related topic?

Answer (score 6):

Look at the google quick answer box for both "caustics" and "prism."
[image: google answer box for "caustics" and "prism"]

While they both are about rendering light based effects, that is where the similarity ends.

No I would not include prisms in the [caustics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caustics) tag, nor synonymize them.

If you feel we *need* a tag for prismatic effects, then I'd normally say just create a new prism tag (even though I think that is is rather ambiguous), however seeing the very low usage of the caustics tag how about we rename it to something like "rendered optical effects." That would include both prisms, caustics, and other effects like refraction.

Comment: I like a group tag, but would be worried that someone may not find it.  `caustics` and `prisms` are common search terms.  Can we synonymize both of them to whatever is the group tag, so when someone types 'prism' for the tag, they see the group-tag + hint text?  I'd try to add these, but I think my rep is too low

Comment: While there might not be many uses of the 'caustics' *tag*, there are plenty of questions [mentioning caustics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=caustics), they're just not tagged correctly. In my opinion 'rendered optical effects' is far too vague and would probably be immediately misused by people who see the word 'rendered' and presume it relates to anything related to rendering. If anything, a new 'refraction' tag could cover anything prism related (caustics does include refraction but also includes reflection).